# understanding Conditional Expectation on a Set and an Elements from the set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$(\Omega ,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ is a probability space,

X is a random variable defined on $\Omega$

$\mathcal G\subseteq \mathcal F$ is a sub-σ-algebra generated by a countable partition $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $\Omega$, formed by F-measurable sets.

I try to follow the answer for this question:[Conditional Expectation of X with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014230/conditional-expectation-of-x-with-respect-to-a-sigma-algebra-mathcalg)

1. My understanding of why $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X|\mathcal G)$ is a random variable is because $\mathcal G$ stands for a collection of possible events so what $\mathcal G$ stands for depends on what we actually put in

My confusion:

Is conditioning on set $A_i$ the same as conditioning on a $\omega \in A_i$? it seems from the answer above, it implies if $\omega \in A_i$ then
$$\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X|A_i )(\omega) = \mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X|A_i ) $$

$$\frac {\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X1_{A_i} )}{\mathbb P(\{\omega\})} = \frac {\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X1_{A_i} )}{\mathbb P(A_i)}. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\Bbb E(X|A_i)(\omega)=\Bbb E(X|A_i)$ is not correct and is not written or suggested by the linked answer. Notice $A_i$ won't be a $\sigma$-algebra, it's an event.

Conditioning on a set is not the same as conditioning on an element of that set. If you like, it's conditioning on all elements. <s>Often $\Bbb E(X|A_i)$ is shorthand for the *number* $\Bbb E(X\cdot1_A)=\int_A X\,\mathrm{d}\mu$</s> - ok, I've seen it used that way, but people also use $\Bbb E(X|A)=\Bbb E(X\cdot1_A)/\mu(A)$ - but if you want to interpret it with the full measure theoretic formalism, you can consider $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(A_i)=\{\emptyset,A_i,\Omega\setminus A_i,\Omega\}$ and you can look at the *random variable* $\Bbb E(X|\mathcal{G})$.

Exercise: prove, in the case $\mu(A_i)>0$, that (up to almost sure equality): $$\Bbb E(X|\mathcal{G})=\frac{\Bbb E(X\cdot1_{A_i})}{\mu(A_i)}\cdot1_{A_i}+\frac{\Bbb E(X\cdot1_{\Omega\setminus A_i})}{1-\mu(A_i)}\cdot1_{\Omega\setminus A_i}$$

Observe that, restricted to $A_i$, $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ is constantly equal to the expectation of $X$ with the subspace "conditional" probability measure $\hat{\mu}(E):=\mu(E|A_i)$.

Conditioning on an event is often about *restricting* a variable to that event, exactly analogous to restriction of functions to a subset. It's less common to think about the conditional expectation as a random variable in the way I did above; if we do do this, we should really write $\Bbb E(X|\sigma(A_i))$ rather than $\Bbb E(X|A_i)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It really help me clarify a lot of stuffs. I thought $\Bbb E(X|A_i)$ means $\frac{\Bbb E(X\cdot1_{A_i})}{\mu(A_i)}$ which is not right. Really confusing......

Comment: @TJT Sorry, it's so confusing I wrote the wrong thing as well. I have *seen* many times $\Bbb E(X|A)=\Bbb E(X\cdot1_A)$ but just double checking online, apparently many people use $\Bbb E(X|A)=\Bbb E(X\cdot1_A)/\mu(A)$ as well! I'll edit my answer to remove that ambiguity

Comment: That's a little bit because $X|A$ is standard notation for restriction of the variable (function) $X$ to the set $A$. Ugh